# How to check are list of objects is different from list of list?

Tags: c#, linq

how can I check if an `int[]` is already in a `List<int[]>`.

For example:
There is `List<int[]> list` and an `int[] arr` and I want to check if all numbers are not the same(order doesn't matter), and if not the same add it to a list.
 How could I do that?
I can't change the order of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want `Order then SequenceEqual` pattern for each element in the list:

```
if(!list.Any(a=>a.OrderBy(i1=>i1).SequenceEqual(arr.OrderBy(i2=>i2))))
            list.Add(arr);
```

Comment: I can't change the order of list

Comment: Create a temporary list and apply the solution to it. In if use for example then `tempList` and the `list.Add(arr);`

Comment: Okey got it thx